# How to fix 'SnowballStemmer' object has no attribute 'StemWords?

Tags: python, nltk, snowball-stemmer

This is the code:

```
import nltk
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
      
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')
      
    stem = []
    lines2 = ["test"]
    for words in lines2:
        stem.append(stemmer.stem(words))
    
    print(stem)
```

The error:

```
line 82, in <module>
    stem.append(stemmer.StemWords(words))
AttributeError: 'SnowballStemmer' object has no attribute 'StemWords'
```

I am very glad for any kind of help to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `stem.append(stemmer.stem(words))`

Comment: Thank you good sir, that worked out pretty good :)